# Unable to access older time machine backups after turning file vault off?

Tags: backup, time-machine, encryption, filevault

I've had FileVault turned one since I purchased my Mac. I recently turned it off and I've found that I can no longer access my older backups from when FileVault was enabled. Is there any way to gain access to these backups or will I have to turn FileVault back on again? Thanks!

Edit : by access, I mean through the time machine UI when I hit "Enter time machine". In preferences, time machine can see the older backups as it says the oldest backup is the day I set time machine up. However, it refuses to let me navigate beyond the backups I made after I turned FileVault off whenever I enter time machine.

Comment: Could you edit this? Physically what does “access” look like to you? The canonical way is to set the backups to be the destination and then turn on TimeMachine and then use the TIme Machine UI to browse back. Hard to guess what you’re doing, but the encryption on the backups is different than the encryption on the main disk. You could have one / the other / both with the same or different passwords. Maybe add in which Apple KB you are following and which specific step is failing you?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. In the time machine preferences, it says my oldest backup is when I bought the machine and set time machine up. However, when I enter time machine and start traversing through the backups, I can't access any backups made before I turned FileVault off. I can only access the ones made after I turned it off.

Comment: Thanks! Just use the edit function going forward if you want to add more detail,  comments go away but the body and edit history shows who changed the post and when.